# How do I add an object to a list in another object and persist it in JSF?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm new to JSF and Java EE and I've been struggling on persisting an Entity named Room which has one or more Beds, which consists of the following code:

```
package ninfa.javahostel.domain;


import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
@Entity
public class Bed {
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
private Room room;

private Integer number;
private Double pricePerNight;
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public Room getRoom() {
    return room;
}
public void setRoom(Room room) {
    this.room = room;
}
public Integer getNumber() {
    return number;
}
public void setNumber(Integer number) {
    this.number = number;
}
public Double getPricePerNight() {
    return pricePerNight;
}
public void setPricePerNight(Double pricePerNight) {
    this.pricePerNight = pricePerNight;
}

}
```

The Entity Room consists of the following code:

```
package ninfa.javahostel.domain;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Room {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String number;
    @OneToMany (cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "room")
    private Set<Bed> beds;
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNumber() {
            return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    public Set<Bed> getBeds() {
        return beds;
    }
    public void setBeds(Set<Bed> beds) {
        this.beds = beds;
    }

}
```

I have a bedRegistrationService which is used to persist and get objects from the dabatase and a roomRegistrationService which is used to persist rooms.
Other than that I have only one controller which is responsible for everything, I know the architecture is really bad but I'm just trying to implement a simple CRUD and get used to JSF. Code is as follows (I tried the backticks for a code span but they seem not to work):

Bed converter: https://pastebin.com/b1ZwYS75

roomRegistrationService: https://pastebin.com/sBaDzrfh

bedRegistrationService: https://pastebin.com/jjsMbVPA

registrationController: https://pastebin.com/cfZeB16d

roomcreate.xhtml: https://pastebin.com/UMCcW7U7

[image]

Form renders correctly with all the beds in the database

Whenever I try to submit I get the following error on console: 10:07:08,205 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.renderkit] (default task-35) WARNING: FacesMessage(s) have been enqueued, but may not have been displayed.
sourceId=roomRegForm:j_idt41[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(roomRegForm:j_idt41: Validation Error: Value is not valid), detail=(roomRegForm:j_idt41: Validation Error: Value is not valid)]

Thinking that I might have to use bed.number as value on the xhtml instead of bed (since the converter parses the html string and converts it to a Bed, I tried to change to bed.number just to see what happens and the following occurs:
[image]

Don't know why "on" is showing instead of the wrong value. I'm pretty much clueless, I think it might have to do with the converter or my lack of expression language knowledge. My only goal is to persist the room with one or more beds. I apologize for the awful English and newbie question, but I've been stuck on this problem for days. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I think I saw the issue, but in the future you should really create a minimal reproducer, instead of dumping all your code. You'll be much more likely to receive an answer, or maybe figure it out yourself in the process.

Comment: And do correct tagging... Issues are in 99.5% of the time NOT jpa AND jsf related at the same time.

Comment: I'd say this is JSF related...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

selectManyCheckbox probably expects the selected item to be present in its known selectItems, so it does an equality check. This check fails because your converter creates a new Bed instance and your Bed class doesn't have hashCode/equals defined. So `bed.equals(sameConvertedBed)` would always fail based on instance equality.

You should define hashCode and equals in your entity classes, e.g. based on instanceof Bed && id equality. Remember about proxies when implementing. I.e. do `other.getId()`, not `other.id`.